# Converting lines in to columns

Tags: python, bash, shell

I used this  script to generate the below output from server `show /system1/swid*" |egrep -w "name|VersionString" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'`, but I am unable to convert these lines into columns. please help me to get some idea to convert this into columns.

```
name=iLO
VersionString=2.73 Feb 11 2020
name=System ROM
VersionString=P89 v2.76 (10/21/2019)
name=Redundant System ROM
VersionString=P89 v2.64 (10/17/2018)
name=Intelligent Provisioning
VersionString=2.70.75
```

## Required output

```
    name=iLO                            name=System ROM                             name=Redundant System ROM                   name=Intelligent Provisioning
VersionString=2.73 Feb 11 2020      VersionString=P89 v2.76 (10/21/2019)        VersionString=P89 v2.64 (10/17/2018)        VersionString=2.70.75
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFgp1.png)

Comment: Columns of what? Are you trying to put this in a dataframe?

Comment: i have updated the question with sample image

Comment: is there some logic, or a requirement, to display the 'columns' as you've shown them in the 'required output'?  is there a particular spacing requirement?  does 'name' need to start in the same column as the first 'i' in 'VersionString=...'? or do you just need the data columnized with a delimiter between columns (eg, Matias' answer)?

Comment: I would suggest you actually paste what `show /system1/swid*` actually outputs because you are piping to both `grep`, `sed` and now possibly `awk` when the latter can do everything.

Comment: Is `grep -w Name|tr '\n' '\t' ` followed by `grep -w Versionstring|tr '\n' '\t'` an option?

Answer (score 1):

If fancy utils are allowed, then using `sed`, [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/), and [*Steve Kinzler's * `align`](https://kinzler.com/me/align/):

```
sed -n 's/.*/&\t/;N;s/\n//p' file | 
datamash transpose | align  -j _ -g 3
```

Output:

```
name=iLO                         name=System ROM                        name=Redundant System ROM              name=Intelligent Provisioning
VersionString=2.73 Feb 11 2020   VersionString=P89 v2.76 (10/21/2019)   VersionString=P89 v2.64 (10/17/2018)   VersionString=2.70.75
```

---

If *center justified* text is required, just add `-a c` a the end, like so:

```
sed -n 's/.*/&\t/;N;s/\n//p' file | 
datamash transpose | align  -j _ -g 3 -a c
```

Output:

```
           name=iLO                        name=System ROM                   name=Redundant System ROM         name=Intelligent Provisioning
VersionString=2.73 Feb 11 2020   VersionString=P89 v2.76 (10/21/2019)   VersionString=P89 v2.64 (10/17/2018)       VersionString=2.70.75
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
awk '
/^name/{ names= $0 ";" names} 
!/^name/ && NF{data= $0 ";" data} 
END { printf("%s\n%s\n",names,data)}' input.txt
```

Which will print :

```
name=Intelligent Provisioning;name=Redundant System ROM;name=System ROM;name=iLO;
VersionString=2.70.75;VersionString=P89 v2.64 (10/17/2018);VersionString=P89 v2.76 (10/21/2019);VersionString=2.73 Feb 11 2020;
```

Hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# these are arrays
declare -a headers
declare -a values

# loop over versions.txt
while read line
do
    # add array elements
    if [ "${line:0:5}" == "name=" ]; then
        headers+=("${line}")
    else
        values+=("${line}")
    fi
done < versions.txt

# start lines
values_line="${values[0]}"
header_line="    ${headers[0]}"
# Loop over arrays
for (( ii=1; ii<${#headers[@]}; ii++ )); do
    # Determine number of spaces to add to header line
    spaces=$(( ${#values_line} - ${#header_line} ))
    # add spaces
    for (( jj=0; jj<${spaces}; jj++ )); do
        header_line="${header_line} "
    done
    # Append current values to lines
    header_line="${header_line}        ${headers[ii]}"
    values_line="${values_line}    ${values[ii]}"
done
# output lines
echo "${header_line}"
echo "${values_line}"
```